# Why does SQL Server run a subquery for each row of the table it's qualifying?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, subquery, database-tuning, optimization

This query runs in ~21 seconds ([execution plan](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9c7c9d6jliyyugt/subquery.sqlplan)):

```
select 
    a.month
    , count(*) 
from SubqueryTest a 
where a.year = (select max(b.year) from SubqueryTest b)
group by a.month
```

When the subquery is replaced with a variable, it runs in <1 second ([execution plan](https://www.dropbox.com/s/25lyr5ia7cx6uqw/variable.sqlplan)):

```
declare @year float
select @year = max(b.year) from SubqueryTest b
select 
    month
    , count(*) 
from SubqueryTest where year = @year group by month
```

Judging from the execution plan, the "select max..." sub-select is run for each of the millions of rows in "SubqueryTest a:, which is why it takes so long.

My question: Since the sub-select is scalar, deterministic and not correlated, why doesn't the query optimizer do what I did in my second example and run the subquery once, store the result, then use it for the main query?  I'm sure there's just a hole in my understanding of SQL Server, but I'd really like help filling it - a couple hours with google haven't helped.

The table is just over 1gb with almost 28 million records:

```
CREATE TABLE SubqueryTest(
  [pk_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
  , [Year] [float] NULL
  , [Month] [float] NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([pk_id] ASC))

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idxSubqueryTest ON SubqueryTest ([Year] ASC)
```

Comment: My wonder is why you have `Year` as float. Sorry, no, that makes sense for [Stardates](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Stardate). But `Month` as float? Really buffles me.

Comment: Can you supply the execution plans?

Comment: @ypercube :) This data behind this came from Access (which is still the front-end).  It was migrated from using the Access-to-SQL-Server migration wizard which likes floats.

Comment: @MartinSmith Execution plans added.

Comment: What is the result of moving your sub-query from the where clause into the body of the query as a inner join? select a.month, count(*) from SubQueryTest a join (select max(year) as [year] from SubQueryTest b) as b on a.year = b.year group by a.month

Comment: By the way what is the point of this table? Is the `pk_id` column referenced elsewhere? If not you should drop it and just have `year,month`. But in that case as there are no other columns it seems a bit of a waste of space and you could just have a table with a row per `month,year` and a count column that you increment.

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone I can't recall the difference in the execution plan, but the execution time was the same when put in a join.

Comment: @MartinSmith the actual table is a lot wider, I removed the unnecessary columns to simplify it for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slow plan **isn't** calculating the `MAX` for each row in the outer query.

In fact it never explicitly calculates it at all.

It gives a plan similar to

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES *
         FROM   SubqueryTest
         WHERE year IS NOT NULL
         ORDER  BY year desc)
SELECT month,
       count(*)
FROM   CTE
GROUP  BY month
```

**Slow Plan (Estimated Row Counts)**

[image]

You have a non covering index on `year asc` so it scans that backwards to get the rows in the first year (shows as a seek because of the implicit `IS NOT NULL` predicate).

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to differentiate between `TOP 1` and `TOP 1 WITH TIES` when estimating row counts.

In this case it makes a huge difference. (estimated 2 key lookup vs actual 4,424,803) so you get an inappropriate plan.

**Slow Plan (Actual Row Counts)**

[image]

You could consider adding `month` into the index on `year` either as a key or included column to make the index covering. The benefit of adding it as a secondary key column would be that it could then feed into a stream aggregate without an additional sort (though for only 12 distinct values a hash aggregate would be fine anyway).

A non covering index on such a non selective column is really pretty useless for the vast majority of queries. The index is totally ignored by the "fast" plan which ends up doing a parallel scan on the whole table and evaluating the predicate on all 27,445,400 rows (in preference to performing the huge number of lookups).

[image]

Comment: Frankly, this seems like a performance/optimizer bug to me.  It's allowed to assume a static, stable result from the subquery and cache it, so why doesn't it just *always* do that, irrespective of the estimated row counts?  When is the plan its chosen *ever* better?

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Well the plan with the variable isn't great either! If there were only a handful of duplicates for the `TOP 1` this *would* be the best plan. The bug to me is that it doesn't look at average selectivity for that column when estimating rows for `TOP 1 WITH TIES`

Comment: Hmmm, this is still confusing/weird.  Why I'm looking at the slow plan and some of the "Estimated subtree cost"s are a *lot* less than the individual IO and CPU costs.  Maybe my brain just isn't working today, but that seems impossible to me...?

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Because it is under a `TOP 1` so they get scaled down for a row goal. SQL Server estimates that the `TOP` will stop requesting rows after the first row is received. In fact as the first  4,424,803 rows out of the index scan have the same year it takes many more than that.

Comment: But ... the estimated number of rows and number of executions are both 1.  How can scaling 1 down to 1 change the subtree estimates?

Comment: Ah.  Sorry to be a pest about this Martin.  This must be some query plan subtlety that I'm just not grokking.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - [Paul White looks at this specifically in his answer here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18746/3690). Does that help?