# Execution plan has TOP operator for query without TOP or ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, execution-plan, top

[image]I have product sales by month temporary table.(subset of much larger historical table) I'm running query to find new product not previously sold in the previous months for a specified 6 month range. So take January as base, in Feb show me all new product sold that wasn't in Jan sales. In March all new product not sold in Jan or Feb sales, etc. For first 5 months query returns sub second. On 6th month, it takes ~5 minutes. Comparing execution plans, on that 6th month, it's showing Top operator in my execution plan that's taking the extra time. But I'm not sorting or using Top X in select. What in my query is causing this? I can wait 5 mins since it's one-off request, but I'm more asking from a learning perspective, I want to understand the why it added to Top operator. Thanks in advance.

```
select divn_nbr, dept_nbr, vendorNumber, pid, nrfcolorNumber, periodcode    
from ##tmpSFA a 
where periodCode = '201512' 
and not exists  
(   
    select 1 from ##tmpSFA b
    where ISNULL(a.divn_nbr, -99) = isnull(b.divn_nbr, -99)
    and isnull(a.dept_nbr, -99) = isnull(b.dept_nbr, -99)
    and isnull(a.vendorNumber, -99) = isnull(b.vendorNumber, -99)
    and isnull(LTRIM(rtrim(upper(a.pid))), -99) = isnull(LTRIM(rtrim(upper(b.pid))), -99)
    and isnull(a.nrfcolorNumber, -99) = isnull(b.nrfColorNumber, -99)
    and b.periodCode IN ('201507', '201508', '201509', '201510', '201511')
)
```

Here are the results and plan:

> [image]
>   [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` can introduce a `TOP 1` (as can `EXCEPT` in some cases). This is because it only cares about the fact that at least one row exists. This is called short circuiting, and you want this - it is much more likely to speed up your query than slow it down. And I'd be really surprised if the `TOP` didn't show up in the plan for different date ranges, unless there was a *substantial* difference in row counts and a different plan was compiled. Maybe you could post the two .sqlplan files somewhere so that we could associate each plan with the query and help determine the reasons for any differences. With a screen shot and the query that allegedly goes with it, there's not a ton to go on.

I'm not convinced that the `TOP` in your case is making this query run for 5 minutes. Rather than just look at the plan, I'd actually investigate what the query is doing for 5 minutes, while it is running, by looking at `sys.dm_exec_requests` - is it blocking? What is the wait type? Since you're using a ##global temp table (why?), this could be due to blocking, but it's unclear from just a screen shot of a plan. Why doesn't your ##temp table have a clustered index? What other indexes does it have? The `TOP` would probably be more efficient if it could sort on something sensible other than the output of a full table scan. You could consider changing the subquery to be `TOP (1) ... ORDER BY` but adding a clustered index (or an index that covers and satisfies all the where clauses in the subquery) should accomplish something quite similar.

For more info on `NOT EXISTS` and alternatives, see [this blog post](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Comment: In fact the Top is not because the anti-semi join 'short-circuits' (it does that anyway, without a visible top). See my answer here http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18746/1192

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this and the short 'quick fix' answer is: add the `HASH JOIN` hint to the query, eg

```
select divn_nbr, dept_nbr, vendorNumber, pid, nrfcolorNumber, periodcode    
from ##tmpSFA a 
where periodCode = '201512' 
and not exists  
(   
    select 1 from ##tmpSFA b
    where ISNULL(a.divn_nbr, -99) = isnull(b.divn_nbr, -99)
    and isnull(a.dept_nbr, -99) = isnull(b.dept_nbr, -99)
    and isnull(a.vendorNumber, -99) = isnull(b.vendorNumber, -99)
    and isnull(LTRIM(rtrim(upper(a.pid))), -99) = isnull(LTRIM(rtrim(upper(b.pid))), -99)
    and isnull(a.nrfcolorNumber, -99) = isnull(b.nrfColorNumber, -99)
    and b.periodCode IN ('201507', '201508', '201509', '201510', '201511')
)
OPTION ( HASH JOIN )
```

Hints should only normally be used as a last resort, so review carefully before you apply.  The longer answer is to do with your table design and the additional `NULL` checking you have to do as a consequence.  You should ask yourself why are all the columns nullable?  What does a record where all columns are null except the period really mean?  That's what your design allows.  Note you can also fix the performance of this query by making all the columns in the table `NOT NULL`.

Just a few other notes: it's unlikely you need to use the `UPPER` function as most SQL Server installations use case-insensitive collations.  Use `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` when the data is inserted into the table, not during joins.  Generally, do not join on functions at all.  Your periodCode column looks like a smart integer (ie a number that knows something) representing yyyymm, so it definitely does not need unicode and is unlikely to be variable in length.  Therefore the correct datatype is CHAR(6).  You could also store this as INT or DECIMAL(6,0).  These small changes will not transform performance but are generally best practice and demonstrate that you understand SQL Server fundamentals such as datatypes and collations.

My complete test rig and results:

```
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('##tmpSFA') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##tmpSFA
CREATE TABLE ##tmpSFA
(
    DIVN_NBR        INT NULL,
    DEPT_NBR        SMALLINT NULL,
    VendorNumber    INT NULL,
    PID             NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    NrfColorNumber  INT NULL,
    PeriodCode      NVARCHAR(6) NULL
)
GO


;WITH cte AS (
SELECT TOP 1000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT 1 ) ) rn
FROM master.sys.columns c1
    CROSS JOIN master.sys.columns c2
    CROSS JOIN master.sys.columns c3
)
, periods AS
(
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES 
    ( 201501 ), ( 201502 ), ( 201503 ), ( 201504 ), ( 201505 ), ( 201506 ), 
    ( 201507 ), ( 201508 ), ( 201509 ), ( 201510 ), ( 201511 ), ( 201512 ) ) x ( period )
)
INSERT INTO ##tmpSFA ( DIVN_NBR, DEPT_NBR, VendorNumber, PID, NrfColorNumber, PeriodCode )
SELECT TOP (200000) 
    rn % 9 DIVN_NBR,
    rn % 3 DEPT_NBR,
    rn % 33 VendorNumber,
    rn % 44 PID,
    rn % 13 NrfColorNumber, 
    periods.period AS PeriodCode

FROM cte c
    CROSS JOIN periods
GO

-- Make some NULLs
UPDATE ##tmpSFA
SET DIVN_NBR = NULLIF( DIVN_NBR, 0 ),
    DEPT_NBR = NULLIF( DEPT_NBR, 0 ),
    VendorNumber = NULLIF( VendorNumber, 0 ),
    PID = NULLIF( PID, 0 ),
    NrfColorNumber = NULLIF( NrfColorNumber, 0 )
GO


-- Delete some of the older rows
;with cte as
(
SELECT *
FROM  ##tmpSFA
TABLESAMPLE ( 50 PERCENT )
WHERE periodCode IN ('201507', '201508', '201509', '201510', '201511')
)
DELETE cte
GO

/*
SELECT PeriodCode, COUNT(*)
FROM ##tmpSFA
GROUP BY PeriodCode
ORDER BY PeriodCode
GO
*/

DECLARE @startTime DATETIME = GETDATE()

select divn_nbr, dept_nbr, vendorNumber, pid, nrfcolorNumber, periodcode    
from ##tmpSFA a 
where periodCode = '201512' 
and not exists  
(   
    select 1 from ##tmpSFA b
    where ISNULL(a.divn_nbr, -99) = isnull(b.divn_nbr, -99)
    and isnull(a.dept_nbr, -99) = isnull(b.dept_nbr, -99)
    and isnull(a.vendorNumber, -99) = isnull(b.vendorNumber, -99)
    and isnull(LTRIM(rtrim(upper(a.pid))), -99) = isnull(LTRIM(rtrim(upper(b.pid))), -99)
    and isnull(a.nrfcolorNumber, -99) = isnull(b.nrfColorNumber, -99)
    and b.periodCode IN ('201507', '201508', '201509', '201510', '201511')
)
OPTION ( LOOP JOIN )    -- Force loop join

SELECT DATEDIFF( second, @startTime, GETDATE() ) diff1
GO


DECLARE @startTime DATETIME = GETDATE()

select divn_nbr, dept_nbr, vendorNumber, pid, nrfcolorNumber, periodcode    
from ##tmpSFA a 
where periodCode = '201512' 
and not exists  
(   
    select 1 from ##tmpSFA b
    where ISNULL(a.divn_nbr, -99) = isnull(b.divn_nbr, -99)
    and isnull(a.dept_nbr, -99) = isnull(b.dept_nbr, -99)
    and isnull(a.vendorNumber, -99) = isnull(b.vendorNumber, -99)
    and isnull(LTRIM(rtrim(upper(a.pid))), -99) = isnull(LTRIM(rtrim(upper(b.pid))), -99)
    and isnull(a.nrfcolorNumber, -99) = isnull(b.nrfColorNumber, -99)
    and b.periodCode IN ('201507', '201508', '201509', '201510', '201511')
)
OPTION ( HASH JOIN )-- Force hash join

SELECT DATEDIFF( second, @startTime, GETDATE() ) diff2
GO
```

[image]

Comment: Adding the HashJoin hint made query run sub-second,similar to the other months. For my temp table, it is subset of much larger historical table I don't maintain. So I had just taken types info of base table. (by using select into) But I see your point about changing what I can for efficiency like using char instead of nvarchar and stripping out spaces when loading instead of on the join, etc. Or Aaron's point above about creating an index on my temp table. I was more curious what caused the Top operator to come into play in this query vs. other 5 months query. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: This could be down to skew, an imbalance between the distribution of the other months versus this one.  The distribution in my sample is artificially uniform.  Could you run `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS( '##tmpSFA', PeriodCode )` and publish the output as text to your Onedrive please?  That would be useful, thanks.

Comment: Attached screenshot to post at top.